# If $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$, prove that $\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c+ab}}+\sqrt{\frac{bc}{a+bc}}+\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b+ac}} \le \frac{3}{2}$.

Tags: inequality

I can't see any ways I could use the fact that $a+b+c=1$. I've tried solving the inequality using various AM-GM inequalities, but I just can't make it. I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note
$$c+ab=c(a+b+c)+ab=ac+bc+c^2+ab=a(c+b)+c(c+b)=(c+b)(a+c)$$
so
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{ab}{c+ab}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{a+c}}\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac{b}{b+c}}\le\dfrac{1}{2}(\dfrac{a}{a+c}+\dfrac{b}{b+c})$$
so
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\dfrac{ab}{c+ab}}\le\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\dfrac{a}{a+c}+\dfrac{b}{b+c}\right)$$
this is true becasue 
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\dfrac{a}{a+c}+\dfrac{b}{b+c}\right)=\dfrac{a}{a+b}+\dfrac{b}{b+c}+\dfrac{c}{c+a}+\dfrac{a}{a+c}+\dfrac{b}{b+a}+\dfrac{c}{c+b}=3$$

Comment: So the inequality $$\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a} \le \frac{3}{2}$$ is well known ? I just know that there is this one: $$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\ge\frac{3}{2}$$Haven't heard of the first one, though.

Comment: By the way, what's next after I know those 2 final inequalities?

Comment: sorry,I have edit.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get your answer. $\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\dfrac{a}{a+c}+\dfrac{b}{b+c}\right)=\sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a}{a+c}$ Do we take it as a theorem that $\sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a}{a+c} \le \frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: Now,do you unterstand?

Comment: Alright, thanks, everything's clear now.